# Disable or remove java 8 thread-dump

Tags: java, logging, liferay-7, thread-dump

I'm upgrading Liferay from version 6.1 GA1 to 7.0.4 GA5 using upgrading tool in java provided by liferay. During the process i have a lot of thread-dumps caused by long waiting time of thread because te operation on DB (16gb of postgres db) take long time.
This is so annoing have all this thread-dumps on my log files. Can I in some way disable or redirect thread-dumps log?

Comment: You mean stacktraces? Shouldn't you investigate them and see if something's wrong?

Comment: @Kayaman nothing wrong. The dump is caused by timeout.

Comment: Timeout of what?

Comment: @Kayaman nice question. I don't know exactly. I think that at the beginnig of upgrade process the upgrade tool run and make wait some threads until the upgrade is complete.

`Thread dump for portal startup after waited 600000ms:`

And after a lots of information about thread current state.

Comment: Here's the code that's responsible: https://github.com/brianchandotcom/liferay-portal/pull/49040/commits/e14faa2903f84872d15d5c811ce354fd0ffbbe67 seems like they hardcoded the 10 minute delay in there, so you can't even increase it. Tsk tsk. I'd say to just ignore the thing. You can always modify your log files afterwards if you don't want them in there.